# Electron - How to pass data to renderer from a new opened window?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm struggling to pass a data from newly opened site window to renderer. What I want to achieve is to find a login button on site and listen on click event. I was reading about webview in electron, but I couldn't make It work. For now I'm stuck on `window.open()` method. Can you please point me what aspect I am missing? Here are my files:

```
//main.js

const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')


function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

ipcMain.on("open-login-window", () => {
  console.info('dostal');
});
```

```
//renderer.js

const electron = require("electron");
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer

const button = document.getElementById("login-button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ipc.send("open-login-window")
  const windowProxy = window.open('https://www.somesite.com/login', null, 'minimizable=false')
  windowProxy.postMessage('hi', '*')

});
```

Comment: what version of Electron are you on? Do you need to set `nativeWindowOpen: true` in your `webPreferences`? Or do you actually want to use a window proxy? Also, it's not clear what issue you're actually running into.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m using electron 18.0.0. Basically I want to display a new window where user should log in. After that I want to get some data from session storage from that window and pass It to the renderer.